# Creating Custom Authorization Attribute with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, custom-attributes

I am very new to MVC, and this is my first attempt at creating a site using it, and simplemembership. The requirement I am dealing with is the need to use both roles and permissions.

So I need an extra authorization method that works just like the roles.
so for example, I need this to work:
    [AuthorizeUser(Permission = "Browse")]

I have found multiple examples for creating custom authorization attributes, but so far none have actually worked for me. The value being passed gets lost, and I keep getting a null value exception.

I have found multiple similar questions, but the code I found with them is not working for me.
Below is a sample of what I have tried based on the code found in various stackoverflow questions.

---

```
public class AuthorizeUser : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string AccessLevel { get; set; }
     protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            if (!isAuthorized)
            {
                return false;
            }

            // My method to get permisions
            userPermissions=getpermsions();


            if (userPermissions.Contains(this.Permission))//**** problem line
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

### }

The problem is this line:
 if (userPermissions.Contains(this.Permission))

this.Permission is ALWAYS null.
I have tried multiple variations of this, and it is always null.

I can use some other alternate means, but it is driving me crazy that this will not work.
It seems like it should.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the name of the property you are using in the call to the attribute in your controller is different from what is specified in the **AuthorizeUser** class.  Change the property **AccessLevel** to be **Permission**.

Like this:

```
public class AuthorizeUser : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Permission { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
```

The call in your controller will set the property value:

```
[AuthorizeUser(Permission = "Browse")]
public ViewResult Index()
```

Comment: Edited answer to correct class name from "ReAuthorizeAttribute".  That is something I use in my own system.